# Is it possible to add a custom folder inside 'drawable' folder of an Android app?

Tags: android

I created this folder, tab_bar, inside 'drawable' and added barbgnd.png. And then in my code, I tried to access it using

```
android:background="@drawable/tab_bar/barbgnd"
```

However, I got this error

> error: Error: No resource found that
>   matches the given name (at
>   'background' with value
>   '@drawable/tab_bar/barbgnd').

My objective is to further organize the files inside the drawable folder.. i.e. all images used in a Navigation Bar component in one folder, etc.

Is this not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're not allowed to create subfolders at drawable folder. I usually use naming prefix to organize files, i.e. navigaton_left.png, navigation_right.png etc.

Comment: thanks for confirming. and that's a great naming convention! i'll do that.

Comment: that naming convention is also used by android itself. ic_ for icons and so on...